# How to take the second array in json?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have use auto complete with json and php. it works, but now I need to get the second array from the json.

This my script on source.php

```
<?php

$req = "SELECT namaBarang, harga FROM masternamabarang WHERE namaBarang LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' ";

       $query = mysql_query($req);

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
       {
           $results[] = array('label' => $row['namaBarang'],'harga' => $row['harga']);
       }

       echo json_encode($results);  
?>
```

and this script for autocomplate.php

```
<html>
   <head>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="json/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() 
      {
       $( "#NAMA" ).autocomplete({
           source: 'source.php'
      });
      });
    </script>

    <script>
    function ambil()
    {
    var x = document.getElementById('NAMA').value;

    document.getElementById('HARGA').value=x;   
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="NAMA" size="50" id="NAMA" onchange="ambil()"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="HARGA"  size="50"  id="HARGA" />

  </form>
</body>
```

The Autocomplete works well, but ALL I need is, take the second array[HARGA] from JSON array and fill it on text box HARGA.

I appreciate your answers.

Comment: you need get harga from json result or php array. If you have json object use . eg myObject.harga..

Comment: I need get harga from json result, and still confuses how to get it on autocomplate

Comment: if you have a object {"label":"Software POS","harga":"1000000"} in array of objects you use myArray[0].harga

Comment: It still not work, I have Try this $myarray[] = array('label' => 'barang1','harga' => '120000');
$json = json_encode($myarray[0].harga);
echo $json;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script.php works fine. It give you json result something like

```
[{"label":"laba","value":"vala"},{"label":"labb","value":"valb"}]
```

you can log (javascript) result in browser like this

```
console.log(data[0].value); // array index 0 for first row, you can try 1,2 etc...
```

you probably need **select** method to bind what was selected:

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: data,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui); // log selected data row
        $('#mySelectedInput').val(ui.item.value); // bind value wherever you like
      }
 });
```

resources
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode($results[1]);
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: No, the echo result is like this [{"label":"Software POS","harga":"1000000"},{"label":"Software POS untuk Butik","harga":"2000000"}}, I need Just Harga : 200000